# Regex with or without https / http or www

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have this regex:

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})
```

which works fine except it accepts a URL like:

```
http://55https//www.google.com/
```

How can I make it not allow something like

```
55https//
```

after

```
http://
```

has already been entered? (or before www or the actual start of the domain name).

The regex accepts these as well:

```
www.demo.com
~http://foo.co.uk/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ^ to anchor your regex to the start of the string, and/or $ to anchor it to the end.

```
(^https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}$)
```